# Find a 3-regular 3-connected graph whose line graph is not Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory

*Exercise 7.3.13* in Combinatorial Mathematics by Douglas B. West.

The complete question is:

Prove that the line graph of a graph $G$ is Hamiltonian if and only if $G$ has a closed trail that contains at least one endpoint of each edge (this holds for the Petersen graph). Use the Petersen graph to construct a 3-regular 3-connected graph whose line graph is not Hamiltonian. (Hint: Make an appropriate substitution for each vertex of the Petersen graph.) (Harary-Nash-Williams [1965]).

I have completed the proof part, but I have no idea how to substitute "every vertex". Please give me some hint if possible.

Comment: Hint: Make an appropriate substitution for each vertex of the Petersen graph.

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov Yes that is the hint given by the textbook, but I am still quite confused about how to "substitute". :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: replace each vertex in the Petersen graph with a $C_3$, splitting the $3$ edges incident to the vertex among the vertices of $C_3$ equally.

From now we label the small vertex in $C_3$ $v$, and each big "vertex" representing the cluster of $C_3$ $V$. Call this graph $G$.

[image]

(For laziness, I only drew the expansion at the first few vertices).

$G$ is $3$-regular and $3$-connected (why). If there was a closed trail $T$ meeting every edge in $G$ once, it must meet every big vertex $V$ in $G$.

Moreover, it must meet each big vertex $V$ **exactly once** (Why? What happens if you have a big vertex $V$ such that a trail goes into $V$, comes out, and goes in again?), implying that if we simply look at the edges between big vertices in $G$, they form a Hamiltonian Cycle for the Petersen graph. But the Petersen graph is famously non-Hamiltonian, so such closed trail $T$ cannot exist.

From the first part of the question, the line graph of $G$ is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you Jung Hon :)